# Convert the angular{{ $index+1}} variable to a javascript integer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, type-conversion, parseint

I have a hidden field in my HTML as :

```
<input id="temp" type="hidden" name="country" value="{{$index + 1}}" ;>
```

Note that the {{$index + 1}} is the index for the ng-repeat wirtten above the hidden tag.

Now I am trying to get the value of this temp hidden variable(trying to get the value of the index).

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var tempo = document.getElementById("temp").value;
console.log(tempo); //This gives me {{index+1}} in the alert box insted of the integer value
</script>
```

I need to perform`{{index+1}}%6` and require the result to be of type integer.

How can I achieve this in the most simplest form.

Comment: What do you mean with "*I need to **perform** {{index+1}}%6*?

Comment: try `ng-value` instead

Comment: Is the hidden input outside the ng-repeat? If true then $index is not set.

Comment: I already answered this in your previous question , you must access that function through the context of angular

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This code is inside an angular div tag which has the the ng-repeat module. 
ngr-repeat module works like a for loop.{{index+1}} works like the counter. I need to get this value as an INTEGER and not string.

Comment: @fnaticRCggwp: what if you replace `{{$index+1}}` with `{{($index+1)%6}}`?

Comment: In addition there are several problems with your code. Render times are different, always will have access to a single value ( that all inputs have the same id) , etc.

Comment: Willem {{($index+1)%6}} works like CHARM ! 
Thanks sir. 
Add it in the answers section, I will mark it as Working :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this: your script (`var tempo`) is running before angular is started.

My question is why you use classic javascript when you can do this with angular framework?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
{{($index+1)%6}}
```